# Prints numbers in a certain sequence or series

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to write a code in C that will print at a given range (0 - 100).

x would only print from 0 to 3, and then 8 to 11, and then 16 to 19 and so on.
y would only print the rest, for example from 4 to 7, and then 12 to 15, and then 20 to 23 and so on.

The output should look like this:

```
x = 0 1 2 3 8 9 10 11 ... 92 93 94 95   
y = 4 5 6 7 12 13 14 15 ... 96 97 98 99
```

Comment: `k = i;
    k = i % divisor;`...what's the purpose? you can get rid of the first statement completely, inn'it?

Comment: `k = i % divisor` will always return a number between `0` and `divisor`. This is how the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) works

Comment: Get a couple of [good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Read about *selection statements* (like `if ... else ...`).

Comment: `93 94 95 96` --> `96 97 98 99`

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/YODfyz)

Comment: or [this](http://ideone.com/WN8vfF)

Comment: I would start the output labelling with `a` not with `x`. You have run out of letters at "and so on"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `%` won't get you far... `k = i % divisor;` will make sure `k` is somewhere between [0,4] (since `divisor = 4`) which is not what you want.

What about using 2 loops?

```
int main(){
  int i,j;
  for(i = 0; i < 100; i+=8){   // increment by 8 to make 0 -> 8 -> 16 jumps
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){    // print 4 values for x and y, starting from the initial value i, and i+4
      printf("x = %d\ty = %d\n", i+j, i+j+4);
    }
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem specification is self-inconsistent.  It specifies:

```
x = 0 1 2 3 8 9 10 11 ... 93 94 95 96
y = 4 5 6 7 12 13 14 15 ... 97 98 99 100
```

There are at least two problems:

1. Groups of 4 should start on even numbers, so the last sets are wrongly grouped.
2. The `x` line should end with `96 97 98 99` and the `y` line should end with `92 93 94 95` (and maybe `100` too, if that should be included in the output).

The code in the question is flawed because of the way it uses `k = i; k = i % divisor;` and because there isn't the necessary nested loop structure.  I suppose that strictly you could write the code without nested loops, but using nested loops is simpler.

The two lines are a bit inconveniently long for display, so it would be better, perhaps, to wrap them at a suitable length.  The code below deals with these various issues.  It exploits the fact that [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) returns the number of characters printed.  It ignores the possibility that `printf()` returns an error (a negative return value).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
** tag      = string at start of line
** start    = starting value
** finish   = last value to be printed
** major    = major increment
** minor    = number of elements in each sub-sequence
** num_wid  = width to use for numbers (1 for minimum width)
** line_wid = wrap lines after this width
*/
static void print_sequence(const char *tag, int start, int finish,
                    int major, int minor, int num_wid, int line_wid)
{
    int count = printf("%s =", tag);
    for (int i = start; i <= finish; i += major)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < minor && i + j <= finish; j++)
        {
            if (count > line_wid)
            {
                putchar('\n');
                count = printf("%*s  ", (int)strlen(tag), "");
            }
            count += printf(" %*d", num_wid, i + j);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    print_sequence("x", 0, 100, 8, 4, 2, 70);
    print_sequence("y", 4, 100, 8, 4, 2, 70);

    print_sequence("x", 0, 100, 8, 4, 2, 160);
    print_sequence("y", 4, 100, 8, 4, 2, 160);

    print_sequence("x", 0, 100, 8, 4, 3, 70);
    print_sequence("y", 4, 100, 8, 4, 3, 70);

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
x =  0  1  2  3  8  9 10 11 16 17 18 19 24 25 26 27 32 33 34 35 40 41 42
    43 48 49 50 51 56 57 58 59 64 65 66 67 72 73 74 75 80 81 82 83 88 89
    90 91 96 97 98 99
y =  4  5  6  7 12 13 14 15 20 21 22 23 28 29 30 31 36 37 38 39 44 45 46
    47 52 53 54 55 60 61 62 63 68 69 70 71 76 77 78 79 84 85 86 87 92 93
    94 95 100
x =  0  1  2  3  8  9 10 11 16 17 18 19 24 25 26 27 32 33 34 35 40 41 42 43 48 49 50 51 56 57 58 59 64 65 66 67 72 73 74 75 80 81 82 83 88 89 90 91 96 97 98 99
y =  4  5  6  7 12 13 14 15 20 21 22 23 28 29 30 31 36 37 38 39 44 45 46 47 52 53 54 55 60 61 62 63 68 69 70 71 76 77 78 79 84 85 86 87 92 93 94 95 100
x =   0   1   2   3   8   9  10  11  16  17  18  19  24  25  26  27  32
     33  34  35  40  41  42  43  48  49  50  51  56  57  58  59  64  65
     66  67  72  73  74  75  80  81  82  83  88  89  90  91  96  97  98
     99
y =   4   5   6   7  12  13  14  15  20  21  22  23  28  29  30  31  36
     37  38  39  44  45  46  47  52  53  54  55  60  61  62  63  68  69
     70  71  76  77  78  79  84  85  86  87  92  93  94  95 100
```

You probably shouldn't submit this code as the answer to the homework assignment.  It is probably too configurable for it to be safe.

#### Single loop code

This implementation of the `print_sequence()` function presents the same external interface, but the implementation is a bit different.

```
static void print_sequence(const char *tag, int start, int finish,
                    int major, int minor, int num_wid, int line_wid)
{
    assert(major > 0 && minor > 0 && major > minor);
    int count = printf("%s =", tag);
    int p_limit = start + minor;        // print limit
    int c_limit = start + major - 1;    // count limit
    for (int i = start; i <= finish; i++)
    {
        if (i < p_limit)
        {
            if (count > line_wid)
            {
                putchar('\n');
                count = printf("%*s  ", (int)strlen(tag), "");
            }
            count += printf(" %*d", num_wid, i);
        }
        else if (i == c_limit)
        {
            p_limit += major;
            c_limit += major;
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

This produces the same output as before.  It is marginally less efficient than the original, but you'd be hard pressed to measure the cost of incrementing `i` a few extra times around the loop.

Also note that both these solutions can print up to `num_wid + 1` characters beyond the specified line length.  You can fix that by adjusting `line_wid` by `num_wid + 1`.  The code could also check that `major` is at least as big as `minor`, and that both are strictly positive; also that `line_wid` is big enough for the tag, the `=` and at least one number.  There's an element of [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) — if you provide bogus parameters, the output will be correspondingly bogus.

Answer (score -1):

I've written a code that has a two lined output
The first line will consist of x values and the second consists of y values.
Hope this would help you out.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {


    int lim, i,j;
    int limit = 100;

    printf("x = ");

    for(i = 0; i <= limit; i = i + 8){
       lim = i;
       for (j = i; j <= lim + 3; j++){ 
           printf("%d ",j);
    }
 }
   printf("\n");


   printf("y = ");

   for(i = 4; i <= limit; i = i + 8){
   lim = i;

    for (j = i; j <= lim + 4; j++){ 

      if (j > 100)
      break;

      printf("%d ",j);
    }
  } 

}
```

Let me explain:

Here I've written 2 for loops because according to the sequence, the 4 consecutive numbers have a difference of 8 between them.
As this sequence has a sub sequence, it is necessary to use 2 for loops.The elements to be removed also follows a similar pattern so, I printed them too.

Comment: Why do you have `lim` as an alias for `i`?  Why do you have separated conditions (`for` limit and an `if-break`) to exit the second loop?

Comment: Yes i agree that using lim was of no use. I used it just for the sake of better understanding.    The break statement is necessary without which the inner loop will print numbers greater than limit = 100. (That is, 101 102 103 104)